# C++ Borland Vector of events

Tags: c++, events, callback

I have the following code:

A.h

```
typedef bool __fastcall(__closure * Callback)();
class A
{
   private :

  Callback FCallback

   public:
    A(); 
    __property Callback OnCallBack = {read = FCallback, write = FCallback};
};
```

then, in other class i have:

```
 a = new A();
 a->OnCallback=b[1].getData; //b is the class called for callback. But not matter for the goal of this example.
```

What i woould like to do in this class is an assignement like:

```
 a = new A();
 a->OnCallback[1]=b[1].getData;
```

So  how i can declare the property in A class to get a vector of callback?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a `std::vector` of callbacks? And the property "returns" a reference to  that vector?

Comment: Yes, i need a vector of callback

Comment: Declare `FCallback` and `OnCallback` as arrays.   `CallBack FCallBack[10]` and `__property Callback OnCallBack[10] = {read = FCallback, write = FCallback}` assuming you want 10 of them.

Comment: Peter :i think there is a problem with the sintax : E2290 array property missing ]